# How can I have it done with regex?

Tags: regex

I want to match, using regex in java, a pattern like this one:

> > listare D:\Programe\NetBeans\Proiecte NetBeans\PATema3Ex2

I have tried, and I can come up with something like this:

```
^(listare)\\s[A-Z][:]((\\\\)((([a-zA-Z]+)|([0-9]+))|(([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)+)|(([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z]+))+))+$
```

Also, is it possible to edit this regular expression for making it accept symbols like: `"!@#$%^&*()_+[]{}"` as characters inside a folder's name? As you can see, what I want to match is a path to a directory.

Comment: Be more precise. Right now, the solution is `.*`, because you haven't said what shouldn't match. Please give examples of non-matching input

Comment: Are you trying to match `listara [systemPath]`?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
^(listare)\s[A-Z]:(\\([^\\]+))+$
```

*add into [^\\] your blocked types

see:
[regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3ajt2)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following into RegexBuddy and seems fine to me..

```
listare D:\\Programe\\NetBeans\\Proiecte NetBeans\\PATema3Ex2
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:  `^listare ([A-Z]:(?:\\[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)+)`
See [the playground](http://regexr.com/3ajt8)

The Group 1 matching group is:  `D:\Programe\NetBeans\Proiecte NetBeans\PATema3Ex2`

It matches the literal "listare" followed by a an uppercase (drive) letter, followed by a ":" character, then it matches one or more groups of "subdirectories", i.e.:  a backslash "\", followed by one or more upper/lowercase characters, followed by any number of upper/lower/numeric characters <-- here, you can change it to add your desired punctuation characters.